# Definition of areas in a Region resource limited by use of GET method

Tags: here-api

The [Region resource](https://developer.here.com/documentation/map-image/dev_guide/topics/resource-region.html) accepts the definition of areas as lists of coordinates.

Unfortunately, since the resource seems to be only expecting GET requests, trying to display various areas or more precisely defined areas is limited by the constraints on the size of the query string.

Is there any possibility of consuming the resource with a POST request instead, like it is already happening with other resources in the API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently POST method is not supported except for the `route resource` and it is limited to payloads of 8K maximum.We can take this request as feedback for a later release if you would like that.

Comment: That would be great. I would suggest extending the possibility to the heat maps resource, also (since it's affected by the same problem).